# custom page by tag?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to create a blog inside my web but I already create the custom page but when i make posts with the tag "Blog" they also appear in my index i just i want them on my page Called Blog.php. How can i do that?

this is my template code

```
    <pre>
 <?php
 /*
 template name: Blog
 */
 ?>
 <?php get_header();  ?>
 <div class="switch">
 <div class="switch-left">
    <span style="text-shadow:0 1px 23px #ff0000;color: #000;">Blog de Noticias</span>
</div>
< /div>
 <div class="main section" id="main">
<div class="widget Blog" id="Blog1">
    <div class="blog-posts hfeed">
        <?php query_posts('tag=Blog'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post bar hentry">
            <h3 class="post-title entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="post-header-line-1"></div>
            <div class="post-body entry-content">
                <div class="box-peli">
                     <span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            $foto = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
                            $src = $foto['0'];
                            echo '<img src="'.$src.'" class="alignnone" alt="'.get_the_title().'" width="114" height="170">';
                         }else{ ?>
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/no-image.jpg" class="alignnone" alt="<?php the_title();?>" width="114" height="170"/>
                        <?php }?>                        
                        </a>
                     </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-pager" id="blog-pager">
        <?php if(function_exists('pagenavi')) { pagenavi(); } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php if(!is_paged()) { ?>
    <div id="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide section" id="slide">
            <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML4">
                <div id="maskolis">
                    <?php get_template_part('postsByTag');?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div> 
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'category-slug-name-goes-here', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
?>
```

Use this code instead of

```
<?php query_posts('tag=Blog');
```

It was close but not quite there, let me know how it worked out for you.

FROM YOUR CODE:

```
<?php query_posts('tag=Blog'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Make it this:

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'category-slug-name-goes-here', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Look inside your WordPress, your slug should be like "blog" or "Blog" if its incorrect it won't work. It is not exactly as displayed for example in WordPress it will show stuff like "Home Blog" but the slug is "home-blog".. Make sure you find a correct slug.

Comment: I'm trying to do is that every post with tag "Blog" just appear in my blog template and not in my index

Comment: This works 100%, I copied it directly of my website.. So you probably didn't enter "slug-name" correctly.

Comment: ok can you please show me an example how my code is gonna look? Because idont know if use the tags <?php and ?> inside my loop.

Comment: thank you. it works but is still showing them in the index.php

Comment: I don't know what you mean it shows them in index but if you are new I will assume that you don't have `single.php`... You also need single.php page that will display individual content for example if you click READ MORE on your article